# usar goto en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente Script. Para extencion .py de python para hacer GOTO pero no se si esto funciona en  Phyton v3.3.3

```
os.system('cls')
    if Resultados1 == 0:
        Resultados1 = 0
        goto .Nivel_1
    if Resultados2 == 0:
        Resultados2 = 0
        goto .Nivel_2
    if Resultados3 == 0:
        Resultados3 = 0
        goto .Nivel_3
    if Resultados4 == 0:
        Resultados4 = 0
        goto .Nivel_4
    if Resultados5 == 0:
        Resultados5 = 0
        goto .Nivel_5
    if Resultados6 == 0:
        Resultados6 = 0
        goto .Nivel_6
    if Resultados7 == 0:
        Resultados7 = 0
        goto .Nivel_7

        label .Nivel_1
        GeneralResultados = Resultados1
        Goto .end

        label .Nivel_2
        GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2/2
        Goto .end

        label .Nivel_3
        GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3/3
        Goto .end

        label .Nivel_4
        GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3+Resultados4/4
        Goto .end

        label .Nivel_5
        GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3+Resultados4+Resultados5/5
        Goto .end

        label .Nivel_6
        GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3+Resultados4+Resultados5+Resultados6/6
        Goto .end

        label .Nivel_7
        GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3+Resultados4+Resultados5+Resultados6+Resultados7/7
        Goto .end


        label .end
        print ('Tu resultado final es: ',GeneralResultados)
```

Me dice error Nombre Goto no esta definido como se que es? Por lo poco que se es una variable pero estoy queriendo hacer como si goto fuera en Bat para ir a cierto lado cuando se cumple una función.

Comment: ver http://entrian.com/goto/ y https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-is-there-no-goto

Comment: Python como muchos lenguajes de alto nivel no implementa goto (además sería un tanto incongruente precisamente en un lenguaje que aboga por la legibilidad del código) y en los lenguajes que lo soportan como C suele ser una mala práctica casi siempre, http://david.tribble.com/text/goto.html. Si usas `if-elif` obtendrías el mismo resultado y mucho más legible, si en vez de variables usas una lista lo resolverías en unas 6 lineas. Por otra parte no entiendo la lógica, haces `if Resultados2 == 0: Resultados2 = 0` y luego `Resultados2/2` lo que es siempre 0/2...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python no tiene sentencia `goto`, y por buenas razones. No contribuye a la legibilidad del código, sino más bien lo contrario, y siempre hay otra forma más estructurada de lograr lo mismo.

Por la sintaxis de tu código de ejemplo, da la sensación de que estás utilizando el módulo [`goto`](http://entrian.com/goto/) (`import goto`) que nunca ha sido pensado para ser usado en realidad, sino que se trata de un "chiste" (publicado el día de los inocentes), y una prueba de que incluso en lenguajes tan legibles como python, es posible hacer cosas ilegibles.

La respuesta de VictorR es parte de [esta otra respuesta en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863481), que es otro chiste, y otra forma de implementar goto de una manera aún más burda.

En definitiva, **no uses goto**.

Quizás si explicaras qué pretendes podríamos darte una forma alternativa para implementarlo. Lo que tienes de momento no parece tener mucho sentido, ya que comparas una variable con cero, y si vale cero, le asignas cero (valor que ya tenía de todas formas). [?]

De momento, tu código es equivalente a lo siguiente (al que no encuentro mucho sentido tampoco):

```
if Resultados1 == 0:
    GeneralResultados = Resultados1
elif Resultados2 == 0:
    GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2/2
elif Resultados3 == 0:
    GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3/3
elif Resultados4 == 0:
    GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3+Resultados4/4
elif Resultados5 == 0:
    GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3+Resultados4+Resultados5/5
elif Resultados6 == 0:
    GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3+Resultados4+Resultados5+Resultados6/6
elif Resultados7 == 0:
    GeneralResultados = Resultados1+Resultados2+Resultados3+Resultados4+Resultados5+Resultados6+Resultados7/7

print ('Tu resultado final es: ',GeneralResultados)
```

Answer (score 0):

**goto** No es parte de la libreria estandar de python, sin embargo puedes implementar tu propia funcion de goto  aunque no es recomendado

```
def goto(line):
    global lineNumber  
    line = lineNumber
```

puedes leer un poco mas del tema [aqui](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/como-utilizar-goto/)

Comment: Como seria eso?